# table data crosses the column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3em}|p{5em}|p{4em}|p{5em}|p{5em}|p{4em}|p{4em}|p{4em}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Mobility Model}}
            &   \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
            \cmidrule{2-8}& \textbf{Basic Description} & \textbf{Adaptability for AANETs} & \textbf{Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates} & \textbf{Safety parameters} & \textbf{Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint} & \textbf{Degree of Randomness} & \textbf{Applications} \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: is an option to make wider text width? for example with adding `\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}` to your document preamble? also reducing font size, for example to `footnotesize`? also is an option to rotate table that it appears in landscape?

Comment: \usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} adding this has no effect.

Comment: please read all my comments carefully and complete. also comment to your previous question. use only one segment from it will not help you nor me to further help you. btw, if you use my answer on your previous question as basis for your, it would be nice first accept it ...

Answer (score 3):

One of the issues you're encountering is that pdfLaTeX never hyphenates the first word of a paragraph. The contents of a cell in a `p` column form a paragraph, in the TeX-specific sense of the term.

The way to enable hyphenation of the first words in some of the cells -- "Adaptability" and "Mechanical" are prime candidates -- is to slip in a somewhat artificial-looking `\hspace{0pt}`. In the code below, this is done by setting up new column type, called `P`, which is a `p` column that sets its contents ragged-right rather than fully justified, while still allowing hyphenation, even of the first word in the cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\begin{tabular}{|P{4.5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|%
                 P{5em}  |P{4em}|P{4em}|P{4em}|}
\hline
\textbf{Mobility Model}
& \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
\cline{2-8}
& \textbf{Basic Description} 
& \textbf{Adaptability for AANETs} 
& \textbf{Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates} 
& \textbf{Safety parameters} 
& \textbf{Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint} 
& \textbf{Degree of Randomness} 
& \textbf{Applications} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two (three) more possible solutions. In all of them I have used the `tabularx` package to make the tables as wide as the textwidth. I have also replaced the `\cmidrule` comand by `\cline` as booktabs' rules don't cooperate well with vertical lines. For an alternative, see the third example.

In the first one, I have used abbreviations for the column headers that are explained below the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1.5cm}|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \cline{1-8}
    \textbf{Mobility Model} &   \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
            \cline{2-8}
            & \textbf{BD} & \textbf{AA} & \textbf{SF} & \textbf{SP} & \textbf{MC} & \textbf{DR} & \textbf{AP} \\
    \cline{1-8}
\multicolumn{8}{p{\textwidth}}{\small BD: Basic Description, AA: Adaptability for AANETs, SF: Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates, SP: Safety parameters, MC: Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint, DR: Degree of Randomness, AP: Applications}
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

---

In the second example, I have used `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package in order to rotate the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Mobility  Model} &   \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
            \cline{2-8}
            & \textbf{Basic Description} 
            & \textbf{Adaptability for AANETs} 
            & \textbf{Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates} 
            & \textbf{Safety parameters} 
            & \textbf{Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint} 
            & \textbf{Degree of Randomness} & \textbf{Applications} \\
    \hline

    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}%
\end{document}
```

---

In this last example I have removed all vertical lines and replaced the horizontal lines by the rules from booktabs. I have also removed the bold from the column headers as it might distract:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.5cm}XXXXXXX}
    \toprule
   Mobility Model &   \multicolumn{7}{c}{Parameter}  \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
            & BD & AA & SF & SP & MC & DR & AP \\
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{8}{p{\textwidth}}{\small BD: Basic Description, AA: Adaptability for AANETs, SF: Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates, SP: Safety parameters, MC: Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint, DR: Degree of Randomness, AP: Applications}
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

(adding this answer separately from the first, as the solution method is quite different)

Your table doesn't seem to be set up to fully span the available width of the text block. If this were my table, I would switch to a `tabularx` environment (with overall width set to `\textwidth`) and drop the unnecessary **bold-facing** of the contents of the header cells. The seven data columns employ a column type called `C`, which is simply a modified, centered version of the `X` column type. A feature is that it's straightforward to allow for varying column widths; the only constraint is that the 7 `C` arguments must sum to `7`, which is the number of columns of this type. A principal formatting goal that guided the width choices was to have no more than four rows in any header cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash%
      \hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L 
    C{0.8}C{1}C{1.5}C{0.8}C{1}C{0.9}C{1} @{}}  % 7 args sum to 7
\toprule
\mytab{Mobility\\Model} & \multicolumn{7}{c@{}}{Parameters}  \\
\cmidrule(l){2-8}
& Basic Description 
& Adaptability for AANETs 
& Support for higher node mobility and frequent topology updates
& Safety parameters
& Mechanical and aero\-dynamic constraint
& Degree of randomness
& Applications \\
\midrule
blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla \\
blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla \\
blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: will you please share the latex code for this

Comment: @monika - Sorry for this gaffe. I've added the code, and also provided a few more comments on how to employ the `C` column type.

Comment: thanks alot sir , is it possible  to convert this into a long table

Comment: @monika - That's a separate, new question, which was in no way hinted at in your posting. Please post new queries to ask new questions.